# Making my RecyclerView perform better

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My app is all about performance, so I would really like to optimize this RecyclerView as much as possible. I have measured how long every part takes to complete, and the whole thing needs about 150ms to load. Here is the RELEVANT code:

```
public class AppAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppAdapter.TabViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private MenuActivity menuActivity;
    private Intent intent;
    private ArrayList<String> stringys = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setUpAdapter(Context mContext, MenuActivity mMenuActivity, Intent mIntent, ArrayList<String> mString) {
        this.menuActivity = mMenuActivity;
        this.context = mContext;
        this.intent = mIntent;
        stringys.addAll(mString);
    }

    @Override
    public TabViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        Log.d(TAG, "CreatingViewholder " + "Time: " + menuActivity.deltaTime());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_tab, parent, false); //Here is where the wait happens
        Log.d(TAG, "ViewHolderCreated " + "Time: " + menuActivity.deltaTime()); 
        return new TabViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TabViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(position, holder);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stringys.size();
    }

    class TabViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView text;
        ImageView image;

        TabViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        }

        void bind(int position, TabViewHolder holder) {
            new LongOperation(text, image).execute(stringys.get(position));
        }
    }
    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        TextView text;
        ImageView image;
        CharSequence textToSet;
        Drawable imageToSet;

        public LongOperation(TextView text, ImageView image) {
            super();
            this.text = text;
            this.image = image;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            textToSet = params[0].getTitle(context.getDefaultSharedPreferences());
            imageToSet = params[0].getIcon(context.getDefaultSharedPreferences());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            text.setText(textToSet);
            image.setImageDrawable(imageToSet);
        }
    }
}
```

I have several ideas/questions about this:

1. Is it possible to reuse this ViewHolder? I'm using it every time, and each inflation takes about 5ms, which adds up quickly because this is a grid, and I have about 40 holders loading when I launch this.
2. If it helps, I am also ready to use another kind of view. I took recyclerview as it made the most sense imo, but if there is a better-performing view I can change to that.
3. Would it help if I used a Linear Layout, and put 4 of the ViewHolders I currently use next to each other? Would my time be then reduced by 4?
4. In the asynctask, I call `context.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` twice. Would it load faster (the async part) if I did it once and had it as a variable to pass?
5. The asynctask it might leak if it isn't static. I assume that's not a problem because it finished very quickly anyways, right?

Comment: Can you post your xmls?

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` is used for long lists, implementation of `ViewHolder` pattern improves performance by re-using Views after they leave the screen. If you have don't have enough items to fill the viewport there's no reason to use it.

Also keep in mind while debugging setting bitmaps is much slower, if possible try building as "release" and see how it performs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your ViewHolder will be reused as you scroll down, but you need at least enough view holders to display what is currently on screen, plus a few more that are just off screen. So when you first load this are there 40 views displayed on the screen? If not, you have an issue.
2. It depends if you can scroll your view a lot.
3. You might get a slight improvement but I doubt it.
4. Shared preferences calls are cached. You don't have to worry about them taking a long time after the first access.
5. Not sure

Other improvements:
You could move your `LayoutInflater` creation to `setUpAdapter()`

What is in `R.layout.item_tab`? Make sure your hierarchy of views is as flat as possible. Use Constraint Layout if you can.

Comment: R.layout.item_tab is just a TextView and an ImageView. It's currently inside a linearlayout, will changing to a Constraint Layout help with such a simple layout?

Comment: Well no that wouldn't save you any inflation time.

Comment: Where is your recycler view located in xml? Posting that might highlight some issues